# Comparing two .txt files in Python and saving exact and similar matches to .txt file

Tags: python, compare, pattern-matching, intersection, file-comparison

What i need is:

```
text_file_1.txt:
apple
orange
ice
icecream

text_file_2.txt:
apple
pear
ice
```

When i use "set", output will be:

```
apple
ice
```

("equivalent of re.match")

but I want to get:

```
apple
ice
icecream
```

("equivalent of re.search")

Is there any way how to do this? Files are large, so I can't just iterate over it and use regex.

Comment: For formatting your text use SO's markdown syntax (look at the right of the page while editing, a help should pop up), not HTML tags. :)

Comment: If you just want all words in B starting with a word in A: `{b for b in input_2 if any(a.startswith(b) for a in input_1}`. This will be O(n^2). Otherwise, could you post the code which you would like to run but is too slow? Then we can at least understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to extract from the files words which are one a substring of the other (including those that are identical) you could do:

```
fone = set(['apple', 'orange', 'ice', 'icecream'])
ftwo = set(['apple' ,'pear' ,'ice'])
# transforming to sets saves to check twice for the same combination

result = []
for wone in fone:
    for wtwo in ftwo:
        if wone.find(wtwo) != -1 or wtwo.find(wone) != -1:
            result.append(wone)
            result.append(wtwo)
for w in set(result):
    print w
```

Alternatively, if you want a similarity based on how strings are similar in the order of their letters, you could use as suggested by Paul in his answer one of the classes provided by difflib:

```
import difflib as dl

fone = set(['apple', 'orange', 'ice', 'icecream'])
ftwo = set(['apple' ,'pear' ,'ice'])

result = []
for wone in fone:
    for wtwo in ftwo:
        s = dl.SequenceMatcher(None, wone, wtwo)
        if s.ratio() > 0.6:  #0.6 is the conventional threshold to define "close matches"
            result.append(wone)
            result.append(wtwo)
for w in set(result):
    print w
```

I did not timed either of the two samples, but I would guess the second will run much slower, as for each couple you will have to instantiate an object...

Comment: would be more efficient if you replaced the nested for-loop with itertools.product:  `for wone, wtwo in itertools.product(fone, ftwo):`

Comment: @Paul - True, I thought to that myself, but I am under the impression (but I did not profile the code) that the 95% of the time will be spend on the `str.find()`'s rather than in the looping, so I considered it a *premature optimisation* (=futile). I might be wrong though, the only way is to time them! :)

Comment: yea, I don't usually fall into the premature optimization trap, but nested loops have always (_always_) been a pet peeve of mine, ever since I learned c++, so when I took up Python and found itertools.product, I tend to reach for it instead of nested loops.

Comment: as to the problem of instantiating the `SequenceMatcher` object every time through the loop, I am curious whether this would be any more efficient: http://codepad.org/FFe7kM8L.  I am setting up some scripts to test this right now.

Comment: if you're still interested, I have the test code and results at http://pastebin.com/G0fp25qu.  long story short, updating a single object is about 20 seconds faster after 1000000 iterations, which isn't too surprising. what is surprising (to me) is that using itertools.product isn't faster at all :-/

Answer (score 2):

you might want to check out [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html)

Comment: Can you advice which function of difflib is the best one?

Comment: @Mephian: until you define what do you mean by "similar match" it's impossible to answer this question. The standard `ratio()` function, for example, will **not** return the list that you asked for (try the code in my answer so you can check yourself).

Comment: @mac did the legwork on that in his edited answer. You should probably give him the 'accepted answer'

Comment: @Paul - true sportmanship! [Although I don't think he can unless you edit your answer first, I believe there is a timelimit]. Unluckily I ran out of votes for today... I will +1 your answer tomorrow though! :)

Comment: @mac: by similar match i mean word with same root. like "ice" - "icecream", or "icecream" - "strawberryicecream" and I am talking about milions of words in each file.

Comment: @Mephian - If same root means "one is a substring of the other one" that it easy and probably faster to solve bypassing difflib. But if you mean that `iced` and `icecream` need to be hits, then difflib is a better choice, but you will have to look at the `get_opcodes()` and it will be **very** slow. As stuff like `ratio()` or `quick_ratio()` will report false positives like `cream` and `stream`....